# Issue with opening .exe in ie9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, exe

Has anyone come across this problem...On our intranet site we have a link (a button) that launches and .exe in a separate popup window. With ie it bypasses the open/save dialog box and just opens. Firefox and Chrome actually have you download the .exe before you run it. Well since some of us have upgraded to ie9 when you launch the .exe it takes about 3 minutes to open(and I wish I was exaggerating on the time). Has anyone encountered this, and does anyone have any advise?

Comment: Are you the developer of this Intranet?  Do you have control over how files are served from it?

Comment: I am not. I am actually new here and new to the dev world. I have the ability to get control...

Answer (score 3):

In our environment, we have a shared folder where the exes are, and we have [registered a custom URL protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (which we called `start`) on all our computers.

Then we just put some links on our web pages, such as `start://whatever.exe`, and when the user clicks that, it runs `whatever.exe`.

Comment: Have you had any complications using ie9 with this approach?

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I've just done the same thing and works great on IE9.

Answer (score 0):

@GSerg Thank you for your advise. That was an option on the table, however we did not want to have to do the registered protocol on each computer. What we ended up doing was creating a click once for the app. and then pointed to the *myapp*.applicaion and it seems to be working so far. Good ole ie9 and headaches!