# How can I launch a VBA script from within Firefox on Windows XP?

Tags: firefox, excel, vba

I'd like to do the following:

In `Mozilla Firefox` by clicking a button or pressing a shortcut the URL of the current browser tab is copied and then `Microsoft Excel (XP)` is opened and a VBA script is launched, which takes the URL as an argument.

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8733381/11683

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your VBA script is in an Excel spreadsheet, and you want it to automatically execute when you invoke the .xls(x) from Firefox.

If so, you can try this:

1) Write your VBA as an "Auto_Open macro" or use the "Open" event on your worksheet:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/running-a-macro-when-excel-starts-HA001034628.aspx

2) Make sure your Windows file associations are set so that Firefox will open your .xls(x) file or link with MS Excel

3) You can use a [file URL](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fileurl.html), format `file://host/path` to link to the document

Comment: How are you going to pass the current Firefox URL to that "Open" event?